# Error while implementing firebase cloud messaging in web

Tags: javascript, html, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am working on a web application in which i am using firebase cloud messaging(FCM) for sending notification to user, i have already created an android application and i am able to receive push messages from firebase, but when i implemented the same for web application it is not working properly. i am getting an error message "An error occurred while retrieving token"
    i had followed all the steps mentioned here
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

```
I have some doubts.

* Whether it is possible to receive notification in http instead on https
* is there any tool to receive push message, so that i cam assume that the server part is working properly
```